# How can I check for a keyword in multiple fields in mongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, mern

I have a mern application that allows users to give testionies.  I have a function in the UserController.js that allows me to query all the users who have a testimony that is not empty.  I also have a keyword search that allows users to search the first_name field by an entered keyword.  It wokrs but I would would like to find a way to search multiple fileds by the keyword entered.

Here is the function that works but only on the first_name field:

```
const getAllTestimonies = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const pageSize = 2;
    const page = Number(req.query.pageNumber) || 1;

    const keyword = req.query.keyword
      ? {
          first_name: {
            $regex: req.query.keyword,
            $options: 'i',
          },
        }
      : {};

    const count = await User.countDocuments({
      ...keyword,
      'details.testimony': {
        $nin: [null, ''],
      },
    });

    const testimonies = await User.find({
      ...keyword,
      'details.testimony': {
        $nin: [null, ''],
      },
    })
      .limit(pageSize)
      .skip(pageSize * (page - 1))
      .sort({
        createdAt: -1,
      })
      .select('-password');

    res.status(200).json({
      testimonies,
      page,
      pages: Math.ceil(count / pageSize),
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});
```

I tried adding another object with last_name and dont' get any errors but it doesn't return any records no matter what I enter.

```
const keyword = req.query.keyword
      ? {
          first_name: {
            $regex: req.query.keyword,
            $options: 'i',
          },
          last_name: {
            $regex: req.query.keyword,
            $options: 'i',
          },
        }
        
      : {};
```

Here is the frontend past of the testimonies with pagination:

```
const Testimonies = () => {
  const { keyword, pageNumber } = useParams();
  const { data, isLoading } = useGetAllTestimoniesQuery({
    keyword,
    pageNumber,
  });

  return (
    <div className="testimony_wrapper scrollbar">
      <div className="text-center">
        <h1 className="text-center">Testimonies</h1>
        <h4 className="text-center">
          Search our members' testimonies for inspiration
        </h4>
      </div>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Loader width="100" height="100" />
      ) : (
        <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <Paginate
            pages={data.pages}
            page={data.page}
            keyword={keyword ? keyword : ''}
          />
          <div className="testimonies">
            <Row className="justify-content-center">
              {data.testimonies &&
                data.testimonies.map((testimony) => (
                  <Col key={testimony._id}>
                    <TestimonyCard testimony={testimony} />
                  </Col>
                ))}
            </Row>
          </div>
          <Paginate
            pages={data.pages}
            page={data.page}
            keyword={keyword ? keyword : ''}
          />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: "_In the keyword object, I've tried adding another object with last_name: {$regex: ... but cannot find a way to make it work._" What didn't work about it? Error, wrong results, something else? What did the code look like with that attempt?

Comment: Stange, I restarted the server and I don't get any errors but id doesn't return any records no matter what I enter

Comment: They probably need to be `$or`'d together. By default there is an implicit `$and`